# how can I determine when the confidence interval of a model hits certain value?

Tags: r

The company I work for has certain COVID infection rate targets before letting people return from home. One of those targets is daily new infections per unit population to be below 10 per 100k. How can I determine when the upper and lower confidence intervals hit that target? See image with annotation in red.

[image: COVID time series with regression + CIs]

Right now, the two vertical lines are entered manually, but I'd like these add them automatically at the intersection points of the upper and lower confidence interval.

Data: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robhanssen/covid19-v3/main/data/sc-casesdeath.csv (filtered after Jan 21, 2021 in image).

Code example (from https://github.com/robhanssen/covid19-v3/blob/main/process_us_data.r)

```r
casesdeathsbylocation %>% filter(date > as.Date("2021-01-21")) %>% 
                        ggplot + aes(x=date, y=casesper100k) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm", fullrange=TRUE) + 
                        scale_y_continuous(limit=c(-50,100), breaks=seq(0,100,10)) + 
                        scale_x_date(breaks="2 weeks", date_labels="%b %d", limit=as.Date(c("2021-01-21","2021-04-07"))) +
                        labs(x="Date", y="Cases per 100k population", title="Cases in South Carolina", subtitle="Cases per 100,000") +
                        geom_hline(yintercept=10, lty=2) +
                        geom_hline(yintercept=5, lty=3) +
                        geom_hline(yintercept=0, lty=1) +
                        geom_vline(xintercept=as.Date("2021-03-09"),lty=2) + geom_vline(xintercept=as.Date("2021-04-02"),lty=2)
```

Comment: It depends on how you calculate the CI.  if you generate the CI within `ggplot` using a fitting function, then it's going to be relatively difficult.  if you calculate the model fit and derive the CI externally before feeding the results into `ggplot`, then it should be realtively easy.  Either way, we need to see your code.

Comment: Internally, ggplot2 probably uses `lm` and `predict.lm` to create the confidence band. (Alternatively it might be `mgcv::gam` or `stats::loess` but that doesn't change the general approach. You don't show any code.) You could fit the model outside of ggplot2 and then use `uniroot` together with `predict` to find x values corresponding to specific y values.

Comment: Added code and source to the original question.

Comment: I've had a look at your whole data. Watch out because your series has a 7 days seasonality and that has an impact on your confidence interval. Check out: `plot(stl(ts(casesdeathsbylocation$casesper100k, frequency = 7), s.window = "periodic"))`. You could have a go with a slt model, however for a correct prediction you should be using an epidemiology model...

Comment: Thanks for that insight. I've had no experience with time series in general.

However, I know management will only be pulling the trigger on people returning to work if the daily infections hit below 10/100k *every day*, regardless of any proven periodicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a linear approximation of the *inverse* of a specified confidence limit (which is linear in this case anyway!) and using it to interpolate the value at which the line hits a specified threshold.

Note that here we are approximating **x as a function of y** (e.g. date as a function of lower CI):

```r
find_value <- function(x,y,target=10) {
    aa <- approx(y,x,xout=target)$y
    as.Date(aa,origin="1970-01-01")  ## convert back to a date (ugh)
}
```

Once we have this helper function, we can use it in a tidy workflow that uses `broom::augment` to generate the confidence intervals.

```r
library(broom)
lims <- (cdbl
    ## fit linear model
    %>% lm(formula=casesper100k~date)
    ## predict/add confidence intervals
    %>% augment(interval="confidence",
                newdata=data.frame(date=
                 seq.Date(from=min(cdbl$date),to=max(cdbl$date)+20,
                              by="1 day")))
    %>% select(date,.lower,.upper)
    ## interpolate to find date corresponding to target value (10)
    ## should use across() but I can't get it working
    %>% summarise(lwr=find_value(date,.lower),
                  upr=find_value(date,.upper))
    ## convert to useful data frame for ggplot
    %>% pivot_longer(cols=everything(),names_to="limit",values_to="date")
)
```

Now you have a `lims` data frame that you can use for whatever you want. Using it in the plotting context:

```r
(ggplot(cdbl)
    + aes(x=date, y=casesper100k)
    + geom_point()
    + expand_limits(x=max(cdbl$date+20))
    + geom_smooth(method="lm", fullrange=TRUE)
    + scale_y_continuous(limit=c(-50,100), breaks=seq(0,100,10))
    + scale_x_date(breaks="2 weeks", date_labels="%b %d")
    + geom_hline(yintercept=10,lty=2)
    + geom_vline(data=lims,aes(xintercept=date),lty=2)
)
```

[image: time series of COVID cases with regression, CIs]

As pointed out in the comments, you will get a more reliable answer if you use a more sophisticated forecasting method.  As long as you get the confidence intervals returned by `augment`, the code here will work.